# Editing installed GNOME themes (using Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, themes

I have a theme installed on my Ubuntu 9.04 desktop. It's quite nice, but there are a few issues, where some styles have been left at the default, thereby leaving white text (set by the theme) on a white background (the default).

More specifically:

- The Control Center has white on white. Mouse over will change it to white on blue.
- Renaming a file on the desktop has white on white. The selected area is white on blue.

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Ubuntu's system themes are in */usr/share/themes*. If you installed the theme manually (drag and drop on the appearance dialog or something similar), it will be in */home/yourname/.themes*

Break out your text editor and start tweaking. Note that the theme will not update in real time. I recommend having the appearance dialog up so you can switch to another style and back to yours. This will update the UI with your changes.

You might also look at your custom theme colors. Those can carry over across themes and make things look fugly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to access a linux desktop at the moment, but if I recall, you can edit the theme file as found in `/usr/share/themes/` or `/usr/local/themes/` There will be no dialog for setting variables, but you have much more control over the appearance.